# Rails test database missing primary key

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database

I am attempting to run Capybara tests in Rails, but they are failing because my test database is missing a primary key on one of the tables. I ran a `rake db:schema:dump` and then `RAILS_ENV=test rake db:schema:load`, but the primary key is still missing.

I have two questions now. Should the schema be capturing all the primary keys in my dev database? If so, how come my test db is not seeing that primary key? If not, what could possibly be causing the mismatch of the databases and what are some potential solutions?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

Found more information. When I run `rake db:schema:dump`, in the resulting schema file I see:

`create_table "model", :id => false, :force => true do |t| ...`

Presumably, this is why the primary key is not being set when I run `RAILS_ENV=test rails db:schema:load`. The confusing part is that my development database does have a primary key on the id. What could be causing the `:id => false` option to be included in the schema?

Comment: Rails builds the `schema.rb` as a snapshot of your database when you run migrations. But sometimes rails fails at keeping the test db schema up to date as you have noticed. Usually `rake db:test:load` fixes the problem.

Comment: Thanks for the input, `rake db:test:load` unfortunately did not solve the problem

Answer (score 0):

The schema dumper uses an AR connection method to get a table's PK. It will *only* include the `:id => false` option when the table *does not* have a PK that corresponds to a table column.

To confirm that the development database table has a PK you can try the following in the Rails development console (replacing `Task` / `tasks` with your model / table name):

```
irb(main):006:0> Task.connection.primary_key('tasks') 
=> "id"
```

See `activerecord/lib/active_record/schema_dumper.rb`

Comment: I am absolutely certain that my dev database has a primary key on the default :id column

Comment: Understood, but it seems AR doesn't agree for some reason and the test above will tell you what AR finds when it looks for a table's PK.  Perhaps there's a problem with the query that `connection.primary_key` is generating.  Hard to say

Comment: To be sure you're dumping the development database (and not production), try: `RAILS_ENV=development rake db:schema:dump`